# VSCode complains syntax of create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jshint, create-react-app

I'm starting to use React in my future projects but there is one problem that I still don't know how to resolve.

So, I created an app using the command '*create-react-app react-app-project*', but when I open it inside VSCode, I receive a few syntax warnings with the *jshint*. For example, the editor complains about the 'import' and the 'jsx'.

There's some jshint configuration that I can import inside my project so these warnings stop?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the syntax detected as "JavaScript" or "JavaScript React"?

Comment: It's Javascript. Actually, I already "solved" the problem. It looks like that jshint can't handle jsx for some reason I don't know. So, I removed the 'jshint' plugin from the editor and the errors stopped.

Comment: Perhaps you should [add that as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) and accept it.

Comment: Try using eslint, I made the switch and have loved it :)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it appears the original issue was solved by disabling the jshint extension.

If you are seeing unwanted errors in a JS file in VSCode and they are not coming from an extension, try setting:

```
"javascript.validate.enable": false
```